# Value of type 'CustomTableCell' has no member delegate

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios11, swift4.1

I have a subclass of UITableViewCell called CustomTableCell which is declared in a swift 4.1. file.

In my view controller with the UITableView I have in cellForRowAt:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier") as! CustomTableCell
cell.delegate = self
```

I get the following error:

```
Value of type 'CustomTableCell' has no member delegate.
```

I declared the UITableViewDelegate at the top.

Comment: Does your custom cell have a property called delegate? It's probably missing its declaration.

Comment: `cell.delegate` != `UITableViewDelegate`. The cell must have its own delegate protocol.

Comment: why the negatives and the close being off topic to programming? just curious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UITableViewDelegate doesn't need `cell.delegate = self`.

If you CustomTableCell has your `Custom Delegate` then only you need to assign it. So if you don't have ant `Custom Delegate` for your `CustomTableCell` remove that line.

For tableView delegate methods you have to add this in viewDidLoad() :

```
yourTableView.delegate = self
yourTableView.dataSource = self
```

Or connect it using `StoryBorad` only.

**Answer for: How do you create a cell delegate in the CustomTableCell class? Just curious**

CustomTableCell.swift :

```
// Custom protocol 
protocol CustomCellDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {
   // Protocol method
   func someFunctionToPassSomeValue(name: String)
}
class CustomTableCell: UITableVieCell {
   weak var delegate: CustomCellDelegate?

  // Your class implementations and outlets..

  //Call your protocol method in some action, for example in button action
  @IBAction func buttonAction(sender: UIButton) {
    delegate?.someFunctionToPassSomeValue(name: "anyStringValue")
  } 
}
```

Then in `ViewController` class you need to assign instance to custom delegate variable.

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier") as! CustomTableCell
cell.delegate = self
```

And implement protocol method :

```
extension ViewController: CustomCellDelegate {
   func someFunctionToPassSomeValue(name: String) {
      print("Delegate is working. Value : \(name)")
   }
}
```

Comment: How do you create a cell delegate in the CustomTableCell class? Just curious

Comment: @cdub Updated my answer to show an example of custom delegate.

Comment: make sure to use "delegate?.****" (if you are not sure if delegate is not nil) or "delegate!.****" (if you are sure that it's not nil) as far as it's optional.

Comment: @Sedo good point as I forgot to add it coz I am typing it here directly. Updated.

Comment: @SharadChauhan I figured. And "func" in front of buttonAction.

Comment: @Sedo It is for understanding i wrote that. To make it perfect it should have @ IBAction also in front of func.